# How much calculus do you actually use (not counting use of a graphing calculator)?

Tags: mathematical-foundations

I'm wondering if it's worth it to pursue some deep study into calculus. Already, I have some familiarity with derivatives, limits, and integrals. Though, I also have a graphing calculator that's helped me in high school and college a algebra.

Comment: The best predictor of what you will need to know (of anything) is what you *want* to do. Unless you can be more specific about that, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: how much time do you have? What other topics could you study? What do you want to do? There is plenty of math to be learned. All is useful, but not necessarily for the same purposes and contexts.